# eclipse ide looses source file destination

Tags: java, eclipse

I have rich client platform project. To ramble through source code I have download from cvs several modules and binded the folder location with the osgi bundles which eclipse added to referenced libraries.

The problem is in the following: every time I start eclipse it forgets my source code location settings and I have to set them again. How to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried using the eclipse cvs plugin to checkout the projects into your workspace?

Comment: What difference would it add? I have checked out source using tortoise cvs and linked source by right clicking on the dependent jar file and selecting there necessary source folder. And what are you suggesting?

Comment: It has always worked for me. I have done it the other way too without problems.

Comment: @Bill, that did not help. I checked out eclipse project into my workspace, and added source location as folder inside the workspace. Behaviour is the same, after restart eclipse looses linked source and I have to link them again.

Comment: Wow. I've seen it lose them when they're not in the workspace, but never like that. Have you tried upgrade/reinstall? Also make sure to start with new work spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably that would be helpful for other eclipse rcp ramblers :). I have occasionally solved this problem. The way I was doing source file binding is probably broken for rcp dependencies and unless eclipse ide team fix it such way is unusable.

Good news there is much better solution - using source plugins (or osgi bundles what is the same). Once you have a source bundle you may add it to your target definition and enjoy source code navigation capabilities that eclipse ide provides.

However if you do not have source bundle, but have source code for some plugin you may create a source bundle. I dont know, if there is some tools for such task, I have managed creatinh my own source bundle taking an existing source bundle as an example and replacing plugin specific data with my own.